# What's up with the women posters/stands?

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

In the mission taking place in the city, I've found two women on paper that would get me an attaboy when attacked in slo-mo blade mode.

The first was a cardboard stand that turned into a cardboard stand of another woman when cut, for some reason.
The second was a poster on a shop window, as pictured below. Cutting it in blade mode removed the tape.

[image: Oh, Kojima, you scallywag.]
[Screenshot source](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=215091931)

Are these purely easter eggs, or is there some reward for cutting all the women?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're just easter eggs, and the most they can get you is an in-game radio call: http://www.ign.com/wikis/metal-gear-rising-revengeance/Pin_Up_Posters

Comment: Ah, and the cardboard cutout is apparently the odd one out, according to a comment on that page. Thanks!